# DataGridView does not show SOME data

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, .net

I created an app for inserting specific data into database and it works fine.
However, when i try to view that data, DataGridView shows just some of those fields.

I stucked here. I tried to delete DataGridView and write code again, but it didn't helped.

```
 private void displayData()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\me\Documents\DataB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Users ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            DataGrid.Update();
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            DataGrid.DataSource = dt;


            conn.Close();

        }
```

I expected completely filled DataGridView, but some fields are empty.
I can see name, username, date of birth, than 5 empty cells, then again i can see salary, education and so on..

Comment: You are using SQL Server (not mysql).  You do not need toe attach file in the connection statement since the database is already connected to the server.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio and try same query to see if you get same results.  The DGV is only displaying what is in the database.

Comment: All fields in database are correctly filled, but i can't show that data to user. @jdweng

Comment: That ExecuteNonQuery and the DataGridView.Update are useless here, not that they are causing the problem though

Comment: it sounds like you might have columns created in your dgv prior to setting a datasource, The datatable will create the columns as needed unless you tell it not to, at which time you will need to set the `DataPropertyName` in the `Unbound Column Properties` manually to the field you want each one to display.

Comment: Delete the DGV and add new one.  the existing one may have properties set that is not compatible with the data. The statement DataGrid.DataSource = dt; will automatically configure the DGV properly.

Comment: It's working now... Thank u so much @jdweng